# Split one array into two

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of date like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [imageName] => WNgrRdqZ
            [alt] => alt text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [imageName] => xoPS0udB
            [alt] => Alt
        )

)
```

And I'm wanted to format it so I get one array of `imageNames`, and one array of `alt`. I can do this simply with a foreach loop, but I'm curious if there's a build in PHP function I could use instead of rewriting something else. I've not found anything useful yet in the PHP manual.

EDIT: It could also be split into 1 array with 2 sub arrays, e.g.

```
Array
    (
        ['imageName'] => Array(..),
        ['alt'] => Array(...)
    )
```

Comment: from the manual: [`array_column`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.array-column.php)

Comment: How did I miss that! Thank you :). If you post that as an answer I'll accept it for you.

Comment: Just take Sudecs answer ;)

Comment: Will do :P when SO let's me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_column()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$imageName = array_column($Array, 'imageName');
$alt = array_column($Array, 'alt');
```

Comment: he want the output array like this Array ( [imagename] => Array ( [0] => WNgrRdqZ [1] => xoPS0udB ) [alt] => Array ( [0] => alt text [1] => Alt ) )

Comment: I see no problem there. Just put the 2 resulting arrays into one after splitting the collumns

Comment: array_column is not supported in early version of php

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_reduce:

```
<?php

$data = array
(
    array
    (
        'imageName' => 'WNgrRdqZ',
        'alt' => 'alt text'
    ),

    array
    (
        'imageName' => 'xoPS0udB',
        'alt' => 'Alt'
    )
);


$reduced = array_reduce($data,function($carry, $item){
    $carry['imageName'][] = $item['imageName'];
    $carry['alt'][] = $item['alt'];
    return $carry;
},array());

print_r($reduced);
```

Working example https://ideone.com/48JXvL

Answer (score 0):

please review this code

```
<?php
$arraystest = array(0 => array('imageName' => 'WNgrRdqZ', 'alt' => 'alt text'), 1 => array('imageName' => 'xoPS0udB', 'alt' => 'Alt'));
$i = 0;
$newarray = array();
foreach ($arraystest as $item) {
    $newarray['imagename'][$i] = $item['imageName'];
    $newarray['alt'][$i] = $item['alt'];
    $i++;
}

print_r($newarray);
exit;
?>
```